# Does creating javascript dll have any advantages over adding it directly using script tag?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on project with larger javascript files.I can add these javascripts in one of the two ways.

1) create a separate class library project and have the javascript files there as embedded resource.Include a reference of the dll into the web project and then include those using scriptmanager as webresource.

2)Have these files in a separate folder and then simply add these files using the script tag and there path.

I am not going to paste the javascripts in my page within the script tag cause they would mess my pages mark up.

So I would like to know which one is better of the above 2 ways.In either of the 2 ways everytime i load the web page i see GET request for the js files.If i create a javascript dll will the browser cache it?

Comment: Check bundling and modifications articles, like [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create "javaScript dll". JavaScript is a client-side stuff, dll is server-side. No matter in which project your javaScripts are, it will still be sent to the client and executed there. So it makes no sense to put JS files to another project (especially as resources)

We usually want to minify and bundle the JS files, so the client will do less requests to the server and also to reduce the amount of data to transfer.

For minifying the JS files I would recommend to use [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension to VS. It is very handy and can make web programming easier.

Minification will remove all unnecessary characters from the JS file and it will also reduce the length of the identifiers (like method names and variable names).

You can learn about bundling [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). It is useful when there are more JS files to load to load all of them at once.